# Redirecting used django invitation links

Tags: python, django

I am trying to update an existing Django app's login process because of a problem I have with the invitation links. If I send an invitation link it works as expected and takes the user through the sign-up form and into the site, but if they try to use that invitation link later to access the site again it give a 500 error (`DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.`). I want to redirect all expired invitation links to the main login page so that they can just login rather than going to the 500 error page.

I am using Django 1.11 and the invitation backend (http://django-organizations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/backends.html)

I see that it has a get_success_url that I can use to send the original login to a home page, but is there a get_fail_url that I can use to send expired invitation links to a main login page? Or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Here is my CustomerInvitations class that I send all /invitation/ urls to:

```
class CustomerInvitations(InvitationBackend):
    form_class = CustomUserRegistrationForm

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(Customer)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return "/"

    def invite_by_email(self, email, sender=None, request=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = self.user_model.objects.get(email=email)
        except self.user_model.DoesNotExist:
            user = self.user_model.objects.create(username=self.get_username(), email=email,
                  password=self.user_model.objects.make_random_password())
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
        self.send_invitation(user, sender, **kwargs)
        return user

    def activate_view(self, request, user_id, token):
        organization_ids = CustomerUser.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).all().values_list("organization_id", flat=True)
        organization_names = Customer.objects.filter(id__in=organization_ids).all().values_list("name", flat=True)
        organization_names = list(organization_names)

        if len(organization_names) <= 2:
            names = " and ".join(organization_names)
        else:
            organization_names[-1] = "and " + organization_names[-1]
            names = ", ".join(organization_names)

        user = self.user_model.objects.get(id=user_id, is_active=False)
        form = self.get_form(data=request.POST or None, instance=user)

        if len(organization_names) and not form.is_valid():
            messages.info(request, "Join "+names+" on the website!")

        return super().activate_view(request, user_id, token)
```

The error appears to occur at the line `form = self.get_form(data=request.POST or None, instance=user)` so I considered using a try-except statement to catch the error, but I would prefer a cleaner, more understandable solution as I will not be maintaining this code.

Pardon me if the solution is something obvious that I am missing. I just started with Django a week ago and this is my first introduction to web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to remove is_active=False and add redirect:

```
user = self.user_model.objects.get(id=user_id)
if user.is_active:
     # Change your login url name
     return redirect('login')
```